# CKEditor Get Preceding Text on the same line

Tags: javascript, dom, ckeditor

I use an instance of CKEditor and I am able to insert text within the CKEditor at the point of the cursor. I want to be able to grab all text left of the cursor to the start of the line.

I've tried finding the X,y coordinates of the cursor and that didn't help. I'm confident that with all of CKEDITOR's tools, this can be done, but I have not been able to figure out which tools to use together to make it work.

```
var theEditor = CKEDITOR.instances.editorFull;
sel = theEditor.getSelection();
obj = sel.getStartElement().$;
range = theEditor.getSelection().getRanges();
container = range[0].startContainer.$;
textlen = typeof obj.textContent === "undefined" ? obj.innerText.length : obj.textContent.length;
offset = range[0].startOffset;
if(container.nodeType === 3) {
  while (container.previousSibling) {
container = container.previousSibling;
if(container.length) {
    offset += container.length;
}else{
offset += container.textContent ? container.textContent.length : container.innerText.length;
    }
  }
}
var pct = textlen > 0 ? offset / textlen : 0;
cursor = Math.floor(obj.offsetHeight * pct);
while (obj.offsetParent) {
cursor += obj.offsetTop;
obj = obj.offsetParent;
}
cursor += obj.offsetTop;
alert(cursor);
```

This was my attempt to figure out where the cursor was located and it works, but I'm not really sure what information I'm getting in the alert so it's not useable to me.

What I want is this hypothetical. In the below text uses | as the cursor and this would be found inside my CDEditor instance:

```
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam ex nunc,      
 tincidunt id |arcu in, semper volutpat nulla. Nunc efficitur egestas magna 
 vitae consequat.
```

Notice the | in "id |arcu". I want to be able to grab the text "tincidunt id " based upon the cursor position. I do not want it to grab anything from the end of the line above that text. Basically, stop at the word wrap.

Any ideas?  Thanks.

Allen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a quite tricky term "line" that used. What if the geometry of the editor changes (resize) and the text wraps at some different point? What if the selection is in a table cell, does *line* equals *table row* then? What if `<p>` is split by `<br>` and there are 2 "virtual paragraphs"?

There's no such thing as line in HTML. There are elements, inline (like `<span>` or `<strong>`) and blocks (like `<p>` or `<table>`). To get the HTML content from the beginning of the closest ancestor block to the position of the caret, all you need is:

```
var e = CKEDITOR.instances.editor1;
var r = e.getSelection().getRanges()[ 0 ];

r.collapse( 1 );
r.setStartAt( ( r.startPath().block || r.startPath().blockLimit ).getFirst(), CKEDITOR.POSITION_AFTER_START );

var docFr = r.cloneContents();

console.log( docFr.getHtml() );
console.log( docFr.$.textContent );
```

Comment: Is there a away to move the cursor to the left 1 character / letter and check for the x,y position of the cursor and do that until the Y value changes, which would mean the cursor when to the next line up as the text was then currently formatted?

Comment: Or on second thought, the reason I need to grab the text is to determine the distance between the cursor and the left side of the <p> element. If I could get the x,y, I believe the X value would then tell me how far I was, or is that just the relative value from the top left of the current window?

Comment: What does console.log do?

Comment: @j_allen_morris: If you ask such a basic question as what `console.log` is it means that you haven't used Google at all. Please, first search, then ask.